# Advice on a quicker way to debug EAR (Java web application)?

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, build

Currently, I'm trying to debug a monster web application... and it's brutal

Here's the workflow:

1. Change a couple lines of code
2. Ant Build (Takes 25 minutes)
3. Delete  tags in JBOSS config file
4. Start JBOSS
5. Point JBOSS at the EAR
6. Open browser to http://localohost:8080/app
7. Find out the couple of lines of code didn't fix the bug
8. Cycle and repeat.

Anyone have advice to speed this up?

It literally take me one hour to write a `logger.log(statement);`

And... we don't have the project properly configured with eclipse, hence the ANT builds and lack of breakpoints.

Comment: *we don't have the project properly configured with eclipse* I'd try to spend some time properly configuring the project in my IDE. It would probably make the whole process a lot easier.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch There are multiple projects that are all interdependent. I don't know where to even start, since the `EAR` depends on all ~10 projects that are in my eclipse view

Comment: You can try something like Jrebel for hot code replacement

Comment: [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/) is an approach to what you need. At first, just hook up in debug mode and make your changes. If it doesn't work try the tutorial or research on your problem. BTW, make sure `Project-> Build automatically IS checked`. [Another howto](https://dzone.com/articles/hot-swap-java-bytecode-on-runtime), [more info](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F).